# Truncation may occur due to inserting data from data flow column (SSIS)

Tags: sql, visual-studio, ssis, dataflow

I am working with SQL and Visual Studio to get Data and put it automatically into an excel file but unfortunately a got a warning at my Data Flow Task and I dont you how to solve it.
[image]

Comment: I guess you need to check lengths of the involved columns.In the dataflow UserName has length 260, in the table its length is 255

Comment: Yes I already thought about that but do you know how to change it?

Comment: The warnings are more like you are trying to move data into a table.

Comment: to increase database column size for example... alter [tablename] alter UserName varchar(260)

Comment: Thank you all I have solved it, I just had to click ignore the warning and than it worked out for me!